# django-allauth multiple signup form for difference user type

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have already searched all the questions in stackoverflow. However, there is no one clearly answered this question yet.

My application contain 2 user types, I added 2 user profiles. 
Anyone can show me how to make 2 signup form? 
Since I'm  new  to django, I have already tried a few solutions but none of them is work...

I'm using python3.4 with django 2.0.2.

Thanks!!

I have tried these before...

```
#model.py
class SupplierProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
nationality = CountryField()
company = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
skype = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        SupplierProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.supplierprofile.save()


#form.py
class SupplierSignUpForm(SignupForm):

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First name', required=False)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last name', required=False)
company = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)
phone = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)
skype = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)
address = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)

def save(self, request):
    user = super(SupplierSignUpForm, self).save(request)
    advertiser_user.save()
    user.account_type = 1
    user.save()
    return user

#view.py
class SupplierSignUp(SignupView):

template_name = 'accounts/signup_supplier.html'
form_class = SupplierSignUpForm
redirect_field_name = 'next'
view_name = 'supplier_sign_up'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ret = super(SupplierSignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ret.update(self.kwargs)
    return ret
```

Comment: why you need 2 sign up form ?? post the code you have tried

Comment: since I need to collect different information from these 2 type of user, I need to use 2 signup form. I just updated my code in my question.

Comment: what are the 2 user types ??  is it depends on user.account_type ??

Comment: the type of users is "supplier" and "distributor". Seems I can't add new field to auth_user. So, I divided it to 2 user profile tables.

Comment: how you decide which signup form is to be displayed ( user types to be saved) ?? Is it decided on backend or can be chosen by user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this model which will make the common profile (If choices are same for both model)

**Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('SUP', 'Supplier'),
        ('DIS', 'Distributer'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    nationality = CountryField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    skype = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**Form**

```
class SignUpForm(SignupForm):
    type = forms.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    widget=forms.Select(choices=TYPE_CHOICES ),
    ) 
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First name', required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last name', required=False)
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)
    skype = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, strip=True)

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(request)
        advertiser_user.save()
        user.account_type = 1
        user.save()
        return user
```