# Creating multiple user roles in all-auth signup

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a signup process that creates multiple (2) user roles. I am relatively new to Django and trying to use a tutorial to help. I would like to create a student and mentor profile in the beginning with just the name and email.

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/supporting-multiple-roles-using-djangos-user-model)

This is my code:
**catalog/forms.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class mentorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="mentor_user")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.CHarField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class studentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="student_user" )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

#create either mentor or student depending on instance
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('****', created)
    if instance.is_student:
        student.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    else:
        mentor.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def save_profile(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    print('_-----')
    if instance.is_student:
        instance.is_student.save()
    else:
        mentor.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

**signup.py:**

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{  student_form|crispy }}
  {{ mentor_form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py:**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

**catalog/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class mentorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="mentor_user")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.CHarField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class studentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="student_user" )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

#create either mentor or student depending on instance
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('****', created)
    if instance.is_student:
        student.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    else:
        mentor.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def save_profile(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    print('_-----')
    if instance.is_student:
        instance.is_student.save()
    else:
        mentor.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

However I am not seeing the option to either create a student or mentor profile in accounts/signup and currently seeing this when I visit the page

> Sign Up Already have an account? Then please sign in.

and

> Sign In If you have not created an account yet, then please sign up
>   first.

in sign-in

**UPDATE**

I have also tried following an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066995/django-allauth-multiple-signup-form-for-difference-user-type) given to a similar question, to use one signup form and give users the option to signup as either a mentor or student.

These are the changes I made.

**catalog/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('STU', 'Student'),
        ('MNT', 'Mentor'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, default=None)
    skype = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, default=None)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, default=None)
```

**catalog/forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from catalog.models import Profile
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class SignUpForm(SignupForm):
    type= forms.CharField(
        max_length=3,
    widget=forms.Select(choices=Profile.TYPE_CHOICES),
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First name', required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last name', required=True)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Email', required=True )
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Phone number', required=True)
    skype = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Skype', required=False)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=500,label='Address',required=False)

    def save(self,request):
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(request)
        user.account_type = 1
        user.save()
        return user
```

and getting the error message

> RuntimeError: Model class catalog.models.User doesn't declare an
>   explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.